# Difficulties in finding Jupiter

Tags: planet, telescope, newtonian-telescope

I am new to astronomy. Jupiter is now visible to the naked eye but I have difficulties in locating it with my (new Newtonian reflector) telescope. The lowest magnification I have is 36X, which I guess is part of the problem(?). Any tips for the beginner..? I feel that if I knew any star constellations, it would help in locating objects.

Answer (score 4):

Go out in the daytime and practice lining up on the leaves of trees on a distant hill or some such. It's easier to find targets when they aren't against a nearly featureless black backdrop. 
If you have a finder scope, likewise align it to the scope's view using a distant daytime target.

At night, look first for the moon to get a feel for how aligning works.